# QT: QUrl with no percent encoding

Tags: c++, qt, get, qurl

QT: I was wondering if there is a way to create a QUrl or another URL class object from string without encoding the final URL. For example, here is a snippet of my code:

```
QString GetJsonStringFromURL(QString url) //url == "192.168.0.111/controller?POSITION|03|100"
{
    QEventLoop eventLoop;
    QNetworkAccessManager mgr;
    QObject::connect(&mgr, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), &eventLoop, SLOT(quit()));  

    QNetworkRequest req( QUrl::fromUserInput(url) ) ; 

    QNetworkReply *reply = mgr.get(req);
    eventLoop.exec(); //wait till reply finished
    QString strReply = reply->readAll();
    return strReply;
}
```

This code accesses a local area network controller requesting it's json with a get method, while passing a parameter in the url. The url i'm passing gets percent encoded to:

"192.168.0.111/controller?POSITION%7C03%7C100"

which i am trying to avoid. The server i'm trying to access is a custom piece of hardware with firmware written in C which doesn't incorporate percent decoding. I would like to avoid doing maintenance on the server side. I have tried going through QUrl class reference but none of the available methods provided the wanted result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible with `QNetworkRequest` since each request requires a QUrl object that does store the destination and is internally converted into an encoded string.

[setRawHeader](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qnetworkrequest.html#setRawHeader) does not work for you, since it can set all HTTP headers except from the URL, that is part of the GET request.

Confirm raw HTTP header format `curl -v http://stackoverflow.com/questions/`

```
GET /questions/ HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: curl/7.37.1
Host: stackoverflow.com
Accept: */*
```

Thus you need an entirely raw [socket connection](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtcpsocket.html) (which I have no experience with).

Comment: Thank you, after two days of research i'm giving up on this, and changing the non-standard URL as it seems that you're right, no matter what i try, the QUrl class parses and encodes the string using standard url conventions.

Comment: Fine :) Then I'd appreciate an upvote and accept of this answers.

Comment: I've accepted the answer, but my rep is too low too upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

Qurl has a decode function. Look at QUrl::decode() otherwise you can prevent encoding when passing it in with QUrl::fromPercentEncoding(url.toEncoded()) but you might lose some string integrity if you have complex query strings.

I have not personally used this but I though I would post as you mentioned you couldn't find anything in the class reference.

Comment: I've seen these methods and tested them, none provided the wanted result. :( I've now tried using fromPercentEncoding and still, the string is encoded again. I guess this Url format is required by the network classes, which is why it doesn't allow wrong formats.